# Cefsharp : NotReadableError: Could not start audio source

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a winform application and I have embedded cefsharp browser in it. I am trying to access microphone but I am getting the below error when I open this url https://test.webrtc.org/

**Failed to access your computer's camera and microphone (NotReadableError: Could not start audio source).**

I have downloaded the CefSharp.MinimalExample-master source code and tried to open the above url.'
I have checked "enable-media-stream" flag is set to true.

What else do I need to change to enable access of microphone. On chrome browser it is working fine as microphone pop up comes and we manually click allow.

Comment: Look in the log file, see if there's any other errors. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file
The `MinimalExample` is working fine for me.

Comment: @amaitland I looked at the log file and found the below error : INFO:user_input_monitor_win.cc(170)] RegisterRawInputDevices() failed for RIDEV_REMOVE: The parameter is incorrect. (0x57).
I googled this error but not found any useful information.

Comment: Have you closed chrome and all other apps that might be trying to use the Mic? Do you have antivirus software that could be blocking access? You can search the chromium source for the error and see if it gives any clues as to what's going on.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for the help. I have an antivirus installed on my system. I disabled it and then it worked fine. But why the antivirus is blocking the app? If I want to redistribute the app how will it work then? I can't tell everyone to disable the antivirus. If there is any alternative?

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17440 has a conversation on the subject,  you can participate there.